# NHibernate single table multiple values

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a mapped class that some of it's value are codes that their actual value exists in another table that has three columns, `value_type`, `value_code` and `value`.

I know the `value_type` foreach field in my mapped class and I want to map it so I will get the `value` where the `value_code` is equal to the code in in the class.

I was wondering how I could map something like that... I would appriciate any asistance in this matter.

Comment: Please add some formatting/line breaks to your question and add a sample.

Comment: Yah, way to vague... Not really sure what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference your question, as others have commented, is poorly formulated and vague and typically unlikely to be answered as is.   But I understand what you are trying to do.

First of all this data model - essentially EAV database design - can be very problematic.  Unless you absolutely have to have it this way, which only occurs in certain types of applications, if at all possible refactor to a normal entity relationship database model and just get rid of this structure.

To map this in NHibernate you will have to do some setup:

1)  First you have to create an inheritance hierarchy.  Create a base abstract class, then from that base class derive a new concrete class, one for each `value_type` field value.  So if `value_type` has three possible values, "Type1", Type2", and "Type3", you will have a base abstract class and then three derived classes, one for Type1, one for Type2, and one for Type3.  Each class will have a property that will hold the `value` column.

2) Create a mapping for the base class and the derived classes.  You must use a single table model.  The discriminator column is `value_type`, and the identifier column is `value_code`.  The property in the class is mapped to `value`.

3)  In the class where you want to access these values you have to change the type of each field to the same type as the class you created for that `value_type`.

That should work for you.